# laravel5.8 How to open a modal window for each item with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, dynamic, modal-dialog

I would like to open a delete confirmation modal window for each item.
And I am using laravel 5.8 and pure javascript.

I succeeded to open a modal, but I need to delete an item one by one dynamically.

For example
There are 3 categories.
1. Vue je
2.React js
3.Angular js

I want to delete them one by one.
So a modal needs to fetch each ID.

Here is my code.
index.html

```
<div class="content">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>Category</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>  
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                <tr>
                <td>      
                    {{ $category->name }} <br>
                </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('categories.edit', $category->id) }}"><button btn="" class="edit-btn">Edit</button></a><br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button  class="modalBtn"  >Delete</button><br>
            </td>      
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

class="modalBtn" triggers a modal.

app.js

```
const openModal = document.querySelectorAll('.modalBtn');
const closeModal = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];
const modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');

openModal.forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', open);
    })

closeModal.addEventListener('click', close);

window.addEventListener('click', closeOutside);

function open() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
}

function close() {
    modal.style.display= "none";
}

function closeOutside(e) {
    if(e.target == modal){
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I noticed that you keep asking questions here on stack overflow but never accept any answers. You asked 14 questions, got a total of 20 answers and never accepted any. Wouldn't it be nice to at least show some gratitude to people who try to help you? Or were all the answers you got unhelpful?

Comment: The title contradicts with the statement in your question. You managed to open a modal? But now you need to do something else? Did you edit your question? Please start a new post for a new question. Don't keep updating the current question.

Comment: I am so sorry, I am new here, and I didn't realize this rule... I will thank all the people who helped me ASAP. Thank you !

Comment: Ok, I will post a new one. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @YoheiUmezu It is not a rule (eg. not accepting will not be punished in any way), but it's expected to mark solved question accepted. It helps people who are answering to see which questions are solved already and do not need attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this for reference.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
```